# How to add scalar in neon?

Tags: arm, simd, neon

I want to do addition using scalar. Here is what I've tried:

```
ex) uint32x4_t result, result2, op, one;

// op + 1

result = vaddq_u32(op, 1); //error, 1 is not vector

one = vdupq_n_u32(1);

result2 = vaddq_u32(op, one); // ok
```

What is the best way to save memory space when doing this?

Comment: You can multiply by a scalar, but not add. It's not a big deal to duplicate a value and then add it.

Comment: Can NEON efficiently generate a vector of all-ones?  If so, do that and then subtract it to add `1`.  (In x86 SSE2, that would be `pcmpeqd xmm1,xmm1` (all-ones, without a false-dependency on most CPUs), `psubd xmm0, xmm1`).  I wouldn't recommend trying to actually use a compare same,same in C with intrinsics; instead write `vdupq_n_u32(-1)` so the *compiler* can generate the constant on the fly as an optimization (again, if NEON can do this efficiently).

Comment: Thank you. we should do it the old way in the future.

Comment: @PeterCordes Remember that ARM requires that dependencies be preserved for memory ordering, so the kind of x86 dependency breaking idiom doesn't work. However, ARM NEON has immediate instructions (VMOV, VORR, VBIC with immediate), and corresponding intrinsics:  `uint32x2_t vcreate_u32 (uint64_t)`, `int32x2_t vcreate_s32 (uint64_t)`.

Comment: @PeterCordes you can assign immediate values by `vmov` on `aarch32`, and `movi` on `aarch64`, a single cycle instruction.

Answer (score 3):

There are no instructions for vector-scalar alu type operations, only multiplications of >= 16bit width on NEON.

Neither are there instructions for add/sub by immediate values.

What you already did is the way it is supposed to be done.

One thing you could try to boost the performance is to declare the vector of 1s as a constant outside of the loop, hoping the compiler to be smart enough not to load the same value over and over each iteration within the loop.

Unfortunately, the available ARM compilers aren't that reliable when in comes to NEON. Checking the disassembly is pretty much a necessety which defeats the point of writing in intrinsics in the first place.

Comment: I know compilers are surprisingly bad (often to the point of unusable) with ARM intrinsics (compared to x86 or PowerPC Altivec), but are they really so bad that they might fail to hoist vector constant creation out of a loop?

Comment: @PeterCordes They are straight terrible. Writing in intrinsics plus verifying the disassembly takes much more time than simply writing assembly codes. And the latter job is rendered useless on other toolchains and versions.

Comment: I mean verifying and modifying the intrinsics code with "the latter job"